# Extract line pattern from a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have a file with multiple entries, in which I want to substitute the header of every entry.

The file content looks something like this:

```
>gi|215277009|ref|NR_024540.1| Homo sapiens WAS protein family homolog 7 pseudogene (WASH7P), non-coding RNA
RNARNARNARNARNA
>gi|389886562|ref|NR_046018.2| Homo sapiens DEAD/H (Asp-Glu-Ala-Asp/His) box helicase 11 like 1 (DDX11L1), non-coding RNA
MORERNARNARNARNA
RNARNARNARNARNA
...
```

And i want to make something like this:

```
>NR_024540
RNARNARNARNARNA
>NR_046018
MORERNARNARNARNA
RNARNARNARNARNA
```

Now I made up a regex that works fine when I run it in `perl` (on a teststring), but when I run the following `sed` command (in ubuntu), nothing happens. What's wrong with this command?

```
sed -ri 's/\>[\w\|]+\|ref\|(\w+)\.\d+\|.*/\>\1/g' rna_copy.fa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` does not use `\w` or `\d`.  You have to use character classes instead.

```
sed -r 's/>[[:alnum:]\|]+\|ref\|([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[[:digit:]]).*/> \1/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk would be a better tool for this:

```
awk -F\| '/^>/{print ">"$4;next}1' test.in
```

or

```
awk -F\| '/^>/{$0=">"$4}1' test.in
```

`-F\|` sets the field delimiter to `|`,
`/^>/` executes that block on lines that start with a `>`,
`">"$4` prints only the part you're interested in,
`next` skips to the next line, and
`1` prints the whole line.

In the second, `$0=">"$4` sets the line to that; it is then printed because of the `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed  -r 's/.*\|(\w+)\.[0-9]+\|.*/>\1/' file
```

---

```
$sed  -r 's/.*\|(\w+)\.[0-9]+\|.*/>\1/' file
>NR_024540
RNARNARNARNARNA
>NR_046018
MORERNARNARNARNA
RNARNARNARNARNA
```

GNU sed works with `\w`, but **not** with `\d`.